# How do I set up a server page in create-react-app for making API requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, create-react-app

I am learning React with create-react-app, building an app where I make a API request to an external source.
I have left this request in the front end whilst I was building the project out, but now I want to move it to a server page in order to hide my API key.

What I don't fully understand is how to integrate a server within the create-react-app environment, and make the appropriate routing to the front end.
In my mind I see the process working like so:

*run npm start > my server page makes api request to third party > server page receives a response > server page serves response in JSON format to front end page.*

NOTE: despite a lot of answers on stackoverflow stating that you can hide api keys in a .env config file, this is not true, as it gets embedded in the final build and is publicly accessible.

Comment: You need a separate server to act as intermediate between your React frontend and the 3rd party API. `create-react-app` is frontend only; consider the server a separate project. If you want to also use node, I suggest expressjs. The express server will provide an API endpoint like `/getweather?city=x` for your React app, store the API secret etc, make the request to the 3rd party API and forward it to your React app, probably as JSON. Note that since the server will run on a different port (at least during development), you'll need to set up cors for express.

Comment: @ChrisG - 'consider the server as a seperate project' - thanks, I hadn't considered it seperate in that way. I have now found an online tutorial on how to setup and connect a create-react-app frontend with a node/expressjs backend

Answer (score 0):

You need a backend server for the task. you can find working eample [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-app-with-node-js-server-proxy)